# How to include mp3 music within .exe file?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

    wplayer.URL = @"Properties.Resources.01.mp3";

    wplayer.controls.play();

}
```

I would like to include this file directly in the `.exe` file.

For the moment, I can only read music from path in my pc. How do I include the music file within my `.exe` ?

Comment: Add them as resources, as in the linked question

Comment: You shouldn't use a string containing the word "Resources". Try `wplayer.URL = Properties.Resources.MusicFile` - notice: (a) no double quotes; (b) refer to resource by its name, not file.